# $f(x,y)=\langle y- \cos y, x \sin y\rangle$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

$f(x,y)=\langle y-\cos y,x\sin y\rangle$

$C$ is the circle $(x-3)^2 + (y+4)^2 = 4$ orientated clockwise.

**Relevant theorems:**

Green's theorem (this is under the Green's theorem section of our book).

**What I Have Tried**

Using Green's theorem, I have come up with the double integral $\iint ( \sin y - 1) \,dA$.  Beyond here, I can't figure out what to do for my limits of integration.  I have come to the conclusion that polar might be the way to go, but am at a loss of how to proceed with that, since I have a circle whose center is not the origin.

If it matters, this is out of Stewart Calculus Edition 7.  It is chapter 16.4 question 13.  The answer is $4 \pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must say that your differentiation went wrong near the beginning of the problem, and thus this problem is a little over complicated from that. The y derivative of the first term in the vector field is $ 1 + \sin y$, and the x derivative of the second term is $ \sin y $ the difference of these two is not $\sin y + 1$.

Comment: Also you have to keep in mind the orientation of the circle isn't the usual orientation, this will be important when you use greens theorem because at first it will seem like you are off by a negative sign

Comment: Thank you for the information.  After correcting that, I get $\iint dA$ is this correct?  If so, I seem to still be making a mistake.  All I can manage to get this to work out to is zero.  I'm using the limits of integration specified in Andrew's answer.

Comment: Well the integration of just dA is just the area enclosed by the curve $ \int \int dA = A $ and you have a circle of radius 2

Comment: And you're welcome, I know how hard a problem can be when an important intermediate step goes astray

Comment: Wow, the integral of dA is just A.  That makes this problem extremely easy.  Thank you.  Since the integral of dA is just a, that makes the answer $A = \pi r^2 = 2^2 \pi = 4 \pi$.

Comment: Yep, these little tricks arise sometimes, not always, then again its similar to how we integrate dx to be x (that is $\int_0^x dx = x $). You might also think of it as adding up the infinite infinitesimal area elements to get the total area.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a double integral over $C$, so one option for your limits of integration will be:

$$\int_1^5 \int_{-4-\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}}^{-4+\sqrt{4-(x-3)^2}} \dots dy dx$$

Explanation: The boundaries of the circle you're integrating over stretch from $1$ to $5$, since it's a circle of radius $2$ centered at $\langle 3, -4 \rangle$.

The $y$-coordinates of the boundary will vary with $x$: we have arrived at the bounds above by simply solving for $y$ from the equation of the circle.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have attempted this method as well.  (Believe it or not, I have been at the question for literally hours.)  I will attempt this method again, and see where it takes me